# Elasticsearch 6 + Kibana + Docker Compose ERROR

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana, elasticsearch-6

Below is my docker-compose.yml

I get the error after executing it

```
ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.elasticsearch2: 'kibana
```

I tried removing kibana `volumes:` because I wasn't using kibana.yml for now. But it keeps with the same problem.

After removing Kibana service it compiles fine. However, I would like to have kibana working with elasticsearx-platinum. What am I doing wrong?

```
version: '2.2'

services:
elasticsearch:
image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-platinum:6.2.4
container_name: elasticsearch
environment:
  - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
  - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=MagicWord
  - cluster.name=docker-cluster
  - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
  - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
ulimits:
  memlock:
    soft: -1
    hard: -1
volumes:
  - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
ports:
  - 9200:9200
networks:
  - esnet

elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-platinum:6.2.4
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=MagicWord
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet

 kibana:
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.4
        volumes:
            - ./kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        container_name: kibana
        environment:
            - KIBANA_ELASTICSEARCH_URL=elasticsearch
            - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
            - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=MagicWord      
        ports: 
            - 5601:5601
        networks: 
            - esnet
        depends_on: 
            - elasticsearch  

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue with the indentation in the `docker-compose.yaml`: all `kibana` service's configuration is under the `elasticsearch2` service configuration.

The correct `docker-compose.yaml` is:

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-platinum:6.2.4
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=MagicWord
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet

  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-platinum:6.2.4
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=MagicWord
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.4
    volumes:
      - ./kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      - KIBANA_ELASTICSEARCH_URL=elasticsearch
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=MagicWord      
    ports: 
      - 5601:5601
    networks: 
      - esnet
    depends_on: 
      - elasticsearch  

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

Comment: Sorry, where is the issue? couldn't locate where you mean

Comment: I get the message `{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-04-24T18:28:46Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-04-24T18:28:46Z","tags":["license","warning","xpack"],"pid":1,"message":"License information from the X-Pack plugin could not be obtained from Elasticsearch for the [data] cluster. Error: No Living connections"}`. How can I fix this?